# Visual Studio: How to differentiate between instances if both open similar solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, branch

We all have to work in Dev Master Trunk and RC Branch. At times, both are opened. Over a period of time, they both start to look similar, right from Solution Name to Solution Hierarchy.

**How to differentiate between them if both are opened?** May be Folder location or something else.

Comment: Right click on solution -> Open folder in file explorer. Inconvinient but fast and easy solution. I always do it like that because i do not see the necessity to install an extension for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [**File Path On Footer** extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShemeerNS.FilePathOnFooter), that will display the file path in the bottom of each opened file.

Even better, you can try the [**Visual Studio Window Title Changer** extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IstvanPasztor.VisualStudioWindowTitleChanger), with which you can customize the title of the window to show exactly what you need to differentiate the two solutions.